# If I have a class, and within this class there is a constructor creating an ArrayList...whats the best way to pass this arraylist to a class method?

Tags: java, variables, argument-passing

Sorry for the silly question, but I cannot seem to find an answer on google. I have written a class, and within the class there is a constructor which creates an arraylist, in the same class there is a method which iterates through the array list by creating an iterator object. As my code stands, however, it is not recognizing the arraylists name, should I store the array list in a class variable, or pass it into the method as an argument ?

What is usually best practice here as this is something that is always getting me ?

My code is as follows if you can't follow my somewhat convuluted explanation ! Apologies ! Thanks a lot for reading :)

```
import java.util.*;
public class Primes {
  public Primes( int initialCapacity) {
    ArrayList<Integer> listOfPrimeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(initialCapacity);    
    //how do I get the above...
    int index = 2;
    while (index != listOfPrimeNumbers.size())
    {
      if (isPrime(index))
      {
        listOfPrimeNumbers.add(index);  
      }
      index++;
    }
  }
  public static boolean isPrime(int candidateNo) {
    Iterator<Integer> iter = listOfPrimeNumbers.iterator( );
    //in here ! ?
    i=2;
    while ( iter.hasNext( ) ) {
      if (candidateNo%i==0 && i!=1) {
        return false;
      }
      else
        return true;
    }
  }
```

(Also, if you see anything horrifically wrong with my code please don't be afraid to call me out on it, the more constructive criticism the better!)
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a private var for your ArrayList and initalize this variable in your Constructor.
Now you can access the list inside your Class :)
hope that helps.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Primes {

  private ArrayList<Integer> listOfPrimeNumbers;

  public Primes( int initialCapacity) {
    listOfPrimeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(initialCapacity);    
    //how do I get the above...
    int index = 2;
    while (index != listOfPrimeNumbers.size())
    {
      if (isPrime(index))
      {
        listOfPrimeNumbers.add(index);  
      }
      index++;
    }
  }
  public static boolean isPrime(int candidateNo) {
    Iterator<Integer> iter = listOfPrimeNumbers.iterator( );
    //in here ! ?
    i=2;
    while ( iter.hasNext( ) ) {
      if (candidateNo%i==0 && i!=1) {
        return false;
      }
      else
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: and Add a getter method to get `listOfPrimeNumbers` because it is a private member

Answer (score 1):

`listOfPrimeNumbers` is a local variable. You can either change it into a static member of the class, make it an instance variable and make `isPrime` non-static, or pass it as a parameter to `isPrime`.

Given the apparent intent of this class I'd make `isPrime` non-static and make `listOfPrimeNumbers` an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reconsider how your class is put together:

- Having all the work done within the constructor is typically not a good idea. Constructors in Java are tricky, generally I try to make them as simple as possible, and have the real work go elsewhere.
- Static methods are overrated, I try to avoid them. If you have some data structure you want your methods to access, make those methods instance methods and have the data structure be an instance variable. Java is supposed to be an object-oriented language, using static methods prevents object-orientation and restricts your options.
- Think about how you want to use the class, and how you'd like to test it, and change the API implemented by the class to match that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to set the arraylist as a class member variable. However you're declaring isPrime as static. Those 2 things don't make sense together. If isPrime doesn't need to be static then simply store the arraylist as a class member. If it DOES need to be static (for whatever reason), you'll need to NOT have a constructor (because it wouldn't make sense with isPrime being static in this case) and create the arraylist somewhere else and pass it as an argument to isPrime.

Edit: on second thought, you don't need isPrime to be static, It should look like this:

```
public class Primes {
  ArrayList<Integer> listOfPrimeNumbers;
  public Primes( int initialCapacity) {
    listOfPrimeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(initialCapacity);    
    //how do I get the above...
    int index = 2;
    while (index != listOfPrimeNumbers.size())
    {
      if (isPrime(index))
      {
        listOfPrimeNumbers.add(index);  
      }
      index++;
    }
  }
  public static boolean isPrime(int candidateNo) {
    Iterator<Integer> iter = listOfPrimeNumbers.iterator( );
    //in here ! ?
    i=2;
    while ( iter.hasNext( ) ) {
      if (candidateNo%i==0 && i!=1) {
        return false;
      }
      else
        return true;
    }
  }
```

However it seems like you have other problems. How will your while loop in your constructor ever end? You're incrempending index every time, but you're only adding something to your list if it's prime.

And in your isPrime method, what's the point of your while loop? You call iter.hasNext(), but don't use what its iterating over. You only ever check `candidateNo` and `i`.